# Outlook Reply Receipt are sending with a < in the beginning

Tags: email, outlook, outlook-2010, barracuda

We have a supplier we get frequent emails from.  This supplier requests a read receipt every time we read their emails.  Something weird happening though is that when our system sends out the receipt we have 1 out of 4 users where it adds a < to the beginning of the email address resulting in an undeliverables email reply.

The email is setup correctly on the users contacts but that shouldn't matter anyways.  We have 3 other users who contact this supplier and I am able to see all of their read receipts in the log outbound and they are correct so I can only think it is a component of Outlook 2010.  Have anyone ever seen this before?

Answer (score 1):

I saw this behavior several times. Usually it's related to Outlook local cache that contain an invalid entry.

You can remove it following this steps :

- open outlook
- compose a new email
- type in the "to:" field the first letter of the email address or name, until it show you the record you are looking for
- click the cross right to the name

You can also remove the entire cache by removing the .NK2 file located in the outlook profile folder.

Comment: I went ahead and removed the .NK2 file and retested this with the user and recipient and it works now.  Thank you

Comment: Scratch that.  This is issue immediately came back up